# Is there a way to build custom expression in SqlKata for the Select/Order clause

Tags: c#, sql, sqlkata

I wanted to pass custom expression to SqlKata

The expected output is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Column1 + ' ' + Column2) FROM Table1
ORDER BY Column1 + ' ' + Column2
```

Comment: What are your "problems"? What is the input, and what is the intended output? What database system are you using? Why is this tagged "C#" when there's no C# code in it? There's nothing wrong with the *syntax* of this for most database engines, but beyond that it gets murky.

Comment: I think he used c# since SqlKata is a C# library

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Raw expressions for cases like this one, something like

```cs
var query = db.Query("Table1")
  .SelectRaw("DISTINCT(Col1 + ' ' + Col2)")
  .OrderByRaw("Col1 + ' ' + ColB");
```

Of course be aware of SQL injection.

check https://sqlkata.com/docs/select#raw and
https://sqlkata.com/docs/order#orderbyraw